# using more than one dependency in job gitlab-ci

Tags: selenium, testing, ui-automation, devops, gitlab-ci

Gitlab-ci: Here is my pipeline of a project with some stages:

```
stages:
  - prepare
  - build
  - deploy
  - build_test
  - test
```

And some stages have more than one job to execute, e.g. using for each oracle database environment (aca, spt, fin..):
[image]

**The question is:**
My pipeline skipped a test job (test:aca), I understood that happened because a job of the same kind of dependencies failed, in that ss the job **deploy:spt** failed, but my test:aca skipped.

Look to the **test:aca** job script:

```
test:aca:
  only: 
   - branches
  allow_failure: true
  stage: test
  tags:
   - teste
  script:
   - test script
  dependencies:
   - test:build_test
   - deploy:aca
```

It doesnt has dependencies with the **deploy:spt**, only with **test:build_test** and
**deploy:aca**. How to enable to run the job **test:aca** ?

Comment: Is `deploy:spt` allowed to fail? It is strange the pipeline went to the 4th stage when there is a failed job in the 3rd

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing `deploy:aca` and only using `test:build_test` as a dependency?

```
test:aca:
  only: 
   - branches
  allow_failure: true
  stage: test
  tags:
   - teste
  script:
   - test script
  dependencies:
   - test:build_test
```